# Need assistance regarding UIViewController life cycle

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

In a chat based app I have `UITableView` which display all friends name, on `didSelectRowAtIndex` I am pushing to `chatViewController` using `navigationcontroller` `push` method.

I have two confusion:

1> When I push `chatViewController` I do it like this

```
 chatViewController *cVc = [[chatViewController alloc]initWithFriendName:@"the name" andId:@"the id"];
```

There can be 10 or 50 or 100 friends, is it correct to call `alloc init` for every friend?

2> When user tap back button to go back to friends list, what happen to `chatViewController's` current instance when it will be destroyed to free memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, if this instance of `chatViewController` is for this specific friend.
2. The back button does a implicit `popViewControllerAnimated:` which pops
   the `chatViewController` from the navigation stack and destroys it (unless you have
   saved a strong reference to that view controller somewhere).

So there will be only one instance of `chatViewController` at a time (created in
`didSelectRowAtIndex` and destroyed by `popViewControllerAnimated:` when the
user goes back to the table view).

Comment: thanks for replying, my mistake cVc is not global, it is for specific friend.

Comment: @S.J: For my answer I had assumed that vVC is a local instance created in `didSelectRowAtIndex`.

Comment: please also view this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333731/need-assistance-regarding-uiviewcontroller

Comment: I would like to invite you to answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657719/please-clear-some-confusions-regarding-uiviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating the global instance of chatViewController and allocting it each and everytime the didSelectRowAtIndexpath: method is called , this is the wrong way as it will un-necessarily utilising the memory and thus degrades the app performance . You must create the local instance in the method didSelectRowAtIndexpath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     ChatViewController *_cvc = [[ChatViewController alloc] initWithFriendName:@"the name" andId:@"the id"];

     [self.navigationController pushViewController:_cvc animated:YES];
}
```

Answer for your second question is whenever the user presses the back button , the instance is destroyed

Comment: In your answer call will be "allocating it each and every time" as well

Comment: Yes, call will be allocating the instances everytime but the lifetime of the instances will be weak and would get automatically destroyed as soon as they are no longer in uses