# Re-assigning RootViewController after successful login

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My iOS app opens with a login prompt. Once the user logs in, it switches to the main view.

In application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, I set the RootViewController to a LoginViewController. The LoginViewController has the AppDelegate as its delegate:

```
LoginViewController *login = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
[login setDelegate:self];
[[self window] setRootViewController:login];
```

If the login is successful, the LoginViewController calls the AppDelegate's userDidLogin method:

```
if([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(userDidLogin)]) {
    [[self delegate] userDidLogin];
}
```

userDidLogin creates a new UINavigationController and assigns it as the RootViewController:

```
- (void)userDidLogin
{
    MainRecordViewController *mainRecordViewController = [[MainRecordViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainRecordViewController];
    [[self window] setRootViewController:navController];
}
```

By adding an NSLog to the LoginViewController's dealloc method, it appears that the LoginViewController is destroyed at that stage and that execution continues as expected.

I haven't done anything to explicitly close the LoginViewController, just relied on the assumption that assigning a new RootViewController will mean that the old one disappears and is tidied away by ARC.

Can I rely on that always being the case? Is this a sensible approach?

Thanks in advance.

James

Comment: Side note: If you are unsure what and what doesn't get released by ARC you can implement the dealloc method and print something like NSLog(@"The instance of MySuperDuperClass was deallocated by ARC").

Comment: Thanks -- I've already done that. That's what I meant by "By adding an NSLog to the dealloc method...". The view appears to close correctly, and it looks like it's always deallocated -- but I was wondering whether I can rely on that always working. I suspect it's fine, but it feels like an assumption that could go wrong...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWindow/rootViewController) of the `rootViewController` property states:

> If the window has an existing view hierarchy, the old views are
>   removed before the new ones are installed.

So if you don't keep your own reference to the `LoginViewController`, it will be destroyed.

Perhaps this: [RootViewController Switch Transition Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703806/rootviewcontroller-switch-transition-animation) is also interesting for you, as it describes how to switch the root view controller
with an animation.

Comment: I like that -- an answer, plus an aesthetic refinement. Much appreciated.