# how to change current viewcontroller if user do not login in swift?

Tags: swift, authentication

i have an ios app with swift
i want to check current user in every ViewController
and if user do not login change ViewControllerto to LoginViewController
whate where do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Re-assigning RootViewController after successful login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334041/re-assigning-rootviewcontroller-after-successful-login)

Comment: If you have a flow in the app then you could do it at the start of the app itself instead checking each and every controller.

Comment: @Mani It's not a duplicate if it's in a different language!

Comment: @thedp Which means, the mentions link has answer for this question but it has written in objective-c instead swift. Right?

Comment: @Mani If the question is not answered in the asked language, it can't be considered answered. Also, as an iOS developer you should know better than to point people to 4 year old answers!

Answer (score 2):

Check if user is logged in at `viewDidLoad`, if not, set the login screen as the root: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow/1621581-rootviewcontroller

If you want it work this way for every ViewController in your app, you can subclass UIViewController, and all your ViewControllers will inherit from that subclassed ViewController.

EDIT: as someone pointed in the comments, it's probably better to check this when the app is launched, or back from background (if you're worried the login session might expire): https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle?language=objc

Comment: how to set login as the root?

Comment: basically, `window.rootViewController = YOUR_LOGIN_VIEW_CONTROLLER`
You should read this https://medium.com/@strawb3rryx7/swift-the-hierarchy-of-uinavigationcontroller-programmatically-91631990f495

Comment: if viewDidLoad not work but in @IBAction work currectly

Comment: @reza I'm not sure I understand what you're asking